EntityFramework / MySQL Nullpointer Exception while generating query
We are using MySQL.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.20 and are currently facing a wild issue:
In a regular base query, we are doing something like this:
query = query.Include("Table1").Include("Table2")
Works, and is fine. If we add another Table, say Table3 - which is just another usual 0..n relation, the Query Generator suddenly throws a Nullpointer exception.
query = query.Include("Table1").Include("Table2").Include("Table3")
The really strange thing is, that this exception is appearing in the SelectStatement.cs where Mysql is generating a query like 1 AS C12 and somehow now misses to set the "ColumnName property", causing a .ToUpper() to fail:
Mysql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectStatement.cs:

Column object:

Column "causing" this is a (artificial) column, generated by EntityFramework itself:

Even wilder is, that if we remove Table2, so just doing
query = query.Include("Table1").Include("Table3")
it starts to work as expected. Somehow the presence of "both" tables messes something up there, but both are totally equal 0..n relations.
Somebody ever encountered this issue?

Inlcude("Table2") ??

s/Inlcude/Include/

just a typo ... ;)

This looks as if your DbContext class has some holes in it.  You will have these types of errors if columns are not explicitly declared within the OnModelCreating method, or if the table relationships aren't set up correctly.

@XavierJ The Issue is, that the "offending column" is non-present in the Model. EMF creates it as an artificial column ... , 1 AS C12 , .... I've Read, it does this to determine the presence of a (left) join without the need to check any other columns as they all may be null despite an successfull join. (Requirement to distinguish between: No Row / Object found to join and Row / Object found, but all properties are null)

@XavierJ When writing a query manual, you would do this, by checking right.key, but probably EMF uses this way, to have it uniform for non-keyed-joins as well.

Please provide a [mre] so we can reproduce the issue.

Please add the entity definitions and configuration for Table1, 2, and 3, specifically any navigation properties for relationships between the three tables. I suspect you may have a 3-way de-normalized relationship defined where an optional, or misconfigured relationship between Table 2 & 3 is bunging up the query generation.
